# How to encrypt db fields in spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I want to encrypt some of the fields using

**@encrypted**

I added the dependencies in **pom.xml**  and i am using spring mongodb repository Mongodb is not enterprise edition but fields are not storing in encrypted format

Comment: Provide basic implementation with dependecy and @Bean if any added

Comment: tried this link : https://github.com/bolcom/spring-data-mongodb-encrypt ..but @Bean used for MongoDBConfiguration